# How to write a program with flexible compile?

Tags: compilation, preprocessor

How to write a program with flexible compile?.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void samplef(int d)
{
   printf(....); // if d=1 no compile this line
   printf(....); // else compile this line
}
```

Comment: You can't control compilation based on particular value of function's param, their values are evaluated at **runtime**, not **compile time**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but it doesn't sound possible.

The compiler doesn't know at the time it compiles your program what the value of `d` will be when the program runs.

I suspect you may have misunderstood the word "compile"...?

Comment: hello i want to compile program in design time not run time

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing. You are looking for [preprocessing](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/PreProcessor.html).

Comment: hello friend! have you a sample program

Comment: Start at #ifdef, google and find stuff like http://www.hobbyprojects.com/c_programming_resource/define-undef-ifdef-ifndef.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like that with the preprocessor, but always is gonna be with defines, not with a variable evaluation, because the compiler doesn't know that value at compilation time.